# Can't get discord.py installed on a seperate venv in linux VM

Tags: discord.py, python-venv

I'm unable to get discord.py installed on a separate venv on my linux VM. I'll run through exactly what's happening. Running python 3.7. I have a discord boy located on `/home/username/mybot/discboy.py`. I created a new venv inside of the script directory - `python3 -m venv /home/username/mybot/venv`. Confirmed that a new "venv" directory is in the /mybot/ directory. I activated the venv by `source /home/username/mybot/venv/bin/activate` . Confirmed as my PATH changed to `(venv) /home/...` . I then installed discord.py `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py` . I confirmed that it installed via `pip3 list`. I then started the bot up. Here is the trace code error `

```
0|mybot  |     import discord
0|mybot  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
0|mybot  | Traceback (most recent call last):
0|mybot  |   File "/home/username/mybot/discbot.py", line 3, in <module>
0|mybot  |     import discord
0|mybot  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
0|mybot  | Traceback (most recent call last):
0|mybot  |   File "/home/username/mybot/discbot.py", line 3, in <module>
0|mybot  |     import discord
0|mybot  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
0|mybot  | Traceback (most recent call last):
0|mybot  |   File "/home/username/mybot/discbot.py", line 3, in <module>
0|mybot  |     import discord
0|mybot  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

To note: installing discord.py outside of the environment WORKS. It appears my script isn't running inside of the environment as I did confirm discord.py is installed to it. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Is it possible that I'm missing another package that discord.py depends on? Here's what's installed on the venv:

```
Package           Version    
----------------- -----------
aiohttp           3.7.4.post0
async-timeout     3.0.1      
attrs             21.4.0     
chardet           4.0.0      
discord.py        1.7.3      
idna              3.3        
multidict         6.0.2      
pip               18.1       
pkg-resources     0.0.0      
python-dotenv     0.19.2     
setuptools        40.8.0     
typing-extensions 4.0.1      
yarl              1.7.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happens to me. In the same directory as your bot, type this in your terminal:

```
pip install --target="." discord
```

This will install the discord library in your directory, allowing your program to directly access it

Comment: That was it. Thank you! What exactly happened there? If it's on the pip3 list why did I need to target to it back to the bot directory? Where did it originally get installed to?

Comment: Python/terminal doesn't recognise your directory as holding your modules. You'll need to append the modules folder to PATH.

Comment: I just fixed the issue. I wanted nothing in my project directory aside from my script and then the env folder. This way I could just delete the env all in 1 shot if needed. I was starting my script using pm2 so it could run 24/7. I believe my pm2 was running it outside the env. I pointed the interpreter for pm2 to python3 in my env folder. This fixed the issue

Comment: @bighelpdiscord Good to hear, glad you solved the issue!